# How to make android:drawable/btn_default transparent

Tags: android, button

I am using btn_default for my background of a spinner and that works nicely.  I would now like to make the btn_default transparent.  I have read about maybe using nine patch to make my own button based on btn_default but I can't find btn_default.png anywhere.  I am not sure if this is how to do it so if someone explain how to make the btn_default transparent it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by transparent? fully invisible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what I ended doing which was to modify the btn_default_normal and removed the background and saved it as btn_default_normal_invisible.  transparency was probably a poor explanation because i really just wanted it all gone so the spinner would look like othe text labels that were not spinners

```
     <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/m1_ss_spinner" 
        android:background="@drawable/btn_default_normal_invisible"  
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

The image you are looking for is in the android sdk folder, i.e.: android-sdk/platforms/android-1.6_r02-macosx/data/res/drawable/btn_default.xml on my mac. Actually it's a statelist drawable that defines what image to use for which button state.

You can copy btn_default.xml and the corresponding images (btn_default_normal.9.png, ...) into your projects drawable folder and edit the png, and make the buttons use your custom btn_default.xml as background. If you copy and change the images you have to obey the License (I think it's the Apache 2).

**EDIT**

There is no image "btn_default.png", just a statelist drawable "btn_default.xml". It lists the images for the different states of the button. Those images are name: btn_default_normal.9.png, btn_default_selected.9.png, btn_default_pressed.9.png, etc.

To find certain images you have to work your way up trough the platform specific res folders. The resources will be in the platform folder of the android version they were introduced. I.e. I can find  btn_default_normal.9.png in **android-1.6_r02-macosx/data/res/drawable** and in **android-1.5/data/res/drawable**, but not in **android-8/data/res/drawable**. This means 1.5 inroduced the resource, 1.6 changed the resource somehow and android-8 is using this resource from an earlier version (maybe 1.6).

Not all resources are public, thats the reason for the error "Error: Resource is not public. (at 'background' with value '@android:drawable/btn_default_transparent')". To use btn_default_transparent.xml, copy btn_default_transparent and the images it references into your projects resfolder.

Comment: I went in the android sdk folder, i.e.: C:\android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable\ folder on my pc and see btn_default.xml AND I also see btn_default_transparent.xml. So i figure if btn_default worked then so should btn_default_transparent but I get an error error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'background' with value '@android:drawable/btn_default_transparent'). I never see btn_default.png either but think btn_default_transparent may do the trick but if it would work.  Anybody care to explain one works and not the other?  thakns in advance

Comment: my project res/drawable folder now has btn_default_pressed.9.png, btn_default_selected.9.png, btn_default_transparent_normal.9.png, and btn_default_transparent.xml.  my spiiner includes this line android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default_transparent" and get the same error about not public.  I am going to search more why but thought I would post in case you can respond before I find a solution.  I am sure its something silly.

Comment: You are still using the ressource from the sdk! You have to copy btn_default_transparent.xml in you project too, maybeit needs to be edited! btn_default_transparent.xml is private! And change the background property in the xml to android:background="@drawable/btn_default_transparent"

Comment: I am learning as fast as I can.  I now understand the difference between @android:drawable and @drawable.  I aslo think I went down the wrong road as the intent was the modify the background of a spinner so it did not have the down arrow, i used btn_default thinking i changed the background with btn_default.png.  So when I decided to do no arrow and transparent maybe I dont need the whole btn_default_transparent button data and just the btn_default_transparent.9.png.  I did now just move the .png into my drawable folder, use it in my spinner background and it kinda works.

Comment: Transparent is not invisible so I am working on changing the .png file to see if that works.  I am just trying to make a spinner look like textview but if touched then a spinner array pops up